# How to draw something center of the screen? - Android

Tags: java, android

i want to draw particles center of the screen in android

here is code:

```
private void drawParticles(Canvas canvas) {
    if (tween >= 1.0f) {
        int i = currentScene + 1;
        currentScene = i;
        currentScene = i % numScene;
    }
    frameStart = (particles.length * currentScene) / numScene;
    frameEnd = (particles.length * (currentScene + 1)) / numScene;
    i = frameStart;
    while (i < frameEnd) {
        particles[i].step(tween);
        particles[i].draw(canvas);
        i++;
    }
    if (tween >= 1.0f) {
        tween = 0.0f;
    }
    tween += factor;
}
```

I successfully draw particles on the bottom center of the screen with this code but i want to make particle position exact center from left right and top bottom

also how this formula is used:

```
frameStart = (particles.length * currentScene) / numScene;
frameEnd = (particles.length * (currentScene + 1)) / numScene;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2; //Gets exact center from left to right
int centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2; //Gets exact center from top to bottom
```